# Postfix Policyd both for SASL and non-SASL mail

Tags: postfix, sasl, policyd

I have configured Policyd v2 (cluebringer) to apply quota on msg count for SASL and non-SASL users. It is easy in policyd [1]. However I don't know how to configure postfix (2.7.1). Right now I have this (non important rules removed):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    =
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
```

`check_policy_service` must be before `permit_sasl_authentificated` to be able to check on SASL users (because `permit_sasl_authentificated` returns OK and no other permissions are checked after it).

But having it here means, that it would count every incoming email attempt in quota - regardless if it will be accepted by postfix or not (because greylist/blacklist and `reject_unauth_destination` are after `check_policy_service`). So all rejected spam would count on recipient users' quota.

How is it possible to have policyd be invoked for both SASL incoming email and for non-SASL email which is accepted for server?

1]: http://lists.policyd.org/pipermail/users_lists.policyd.org/2012-October/004002.html

Comment: Why cant you add all `reject` restrictions first, followed by `check_policy_service` followed by `permit` clauses?

Comment: For example `reject_unauth_destination` (rejects all mail for which postfix is not final destination) must be after `permit_sasl_authenticated` otherwise SASL auth would not work.

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade postfix to version 2.10. This version has feature `smtpd_relay_restriction` to separate permit_sasl and check policy

Answer (score 1):

In case of **Postfix version 2.10 or newer**, you can try to solved those problem by using `smtpd_relay_restriction` feature. Snippet from [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#danger) explains how to use them properly.

> Relay policy is specified under smtpd_relay_restrictions, and the spam blocking policy under smtpd_recipient_restrictions.

Then your configuration should like this

```
smtpd_relay_restriction = 
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

Comment: Will this call policyd before rejecting email by spamhaus? I want to avoid that. I just want to invoke policyd only for otherwise accepted emails (SASL or non-SASL), so that I can enforce quotas on them.

Comment: In that case, just reorder to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031`
    `